# Did Tomb Raider on Saturn have fewer save crystals than the PlayStation port?

Tags: sony-playstation, game, ports, sega

I've been trying to find this out for ages. Having owned the Saturn version (which was the original release, BTW) when it was new, but also playing the PlayStation version at a cousin's house, I could've sworn back then that there were fewer save crystals in the Saturn version, thus making the Saturn version significantly harder. I could see that; maybe they got feedback such as "it's too difficult", and added in some more save crystals for the PS release?

I've tried to search for this information many times, the last time just now, but I never seem to find any comparison page which mentions this. It may be one of those things which I just imagined when I was a kid, and then it slowly turned into a "fact" in my own head.

Comment: Migrate to Gaming stack exchange. Not about computer architecture or retro computer use. (Is there another way to flag for migration rather than closure?)

Comment: @knol not until we leave beta.

Answer (score 4):

According to this website, https://segaretro.org/Tomb_Raider
"The European Saturn version also have minor differences to level layouts (specifically some secret areas) because it was rushed to launch three months before the PlayStation version. This was fixed in the North American and Japanese versions."

Maybe these differences are what you remember?

I can find no evidence of specific changes in save points.